# Cross Compiling Python setup

Tags: python, cross-compiling, mingw-w64, gobject-introspection

I am trying to build GObject-Introspection on Ubuntu 14.04 using Mingw-w64. I am currently running 64bit Linux and trying to build for a 32bit Windows target.

My first attempt used Python 2.7.8 installed in Wine, however, this did not work because Python's path separator was set to '\' (well '\') instead of Linux's '/'. Due to this I tried using the Python 2.7 in Ubuntu.

Using the Python provided by Ubuntu doesn't get past the configuration step. Config.log shows the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from conftest.c:40:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch locatio#
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from conftest.c:40:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch locatio#
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:0,
                 from conftest.c:40:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:241:9: error: #error "This platform's pyconfig.#
 #       error "This platform's pyconfig.h needs to define PY_FORMAT_SIZE_T"
         ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pymath.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:77,
                 from conftest.c:40:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch locatio#
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
```

I understand that there are some differences between the platforms that pyconfig.h defines. Should I be gathering these files into seperate directories like the OS seems to be doing (/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h)? What is the correct setup for Python so that I can cross-compile GObject-Introspection?

### Environment setup

```
export PREFIX=$CROSS_DIR/windows
export INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX
export TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$PREFIX/toolchain_windows.cmake

export PLATFORM=WINDOWS

export HOST=i686-w64-mingw32
export BUILD=x86_64-linux-gnu

export COMPILER_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/$HOST/include
export COMPILER_LIB_DIR=/usr/$HOST/lib
export MINGW_32_LIBS=/usr/lib/gcc/$HOST/4.8


export CFLAGS="-I$PREFIX/include -I$COMPILER_INCLUDE_DIR"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$PREFIX/include -I$COMPILER_INCLUDE_DIR"
export CXXFLAGS="-I$PREFIX/include -I$COMPILER_INCLUDE_DIR"
export LDFLAGS="-L$PREFIX/lib -L$COMPILER_LIB_DIR"
export XDG_DATA_DIRS="$PREFIX/share"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib:$PREFIX/bin:$COMPILER_LIB_DIR
export LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib:$PREFIX/bin:$COMPILER_LIB_DIR
export INCLUDE_PATH=$PREFIX/include:$COMPILER_INCLUDE_DIR
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$PREFIX/include:$COMPILER_INCLUDE_DIR
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$PREFIX/include:$COMPILER_INCLUDE_DIR


export CC=$HOST-gcc
export CXX=$HOST-g++
export LD=$HOST-ld
export RANLIB=$HOST-ranlib
export AR=$HOST-ar
export AS=$HOST-as
export STRIP=$HOST-strip


export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig
```

### Configure Windows Python Run

```
./configure --build="$BUILD" --host="$HOST" --prefix="$PREFIX" \
            PKG_CONFIG="$PREFIX/bin/pkg-config.exe" \
            PYTHON="$WINE_PYTHON_PATH/python.exe" \
            PYTHON_INCLUDES="-I$WINE_PYTHON_PATH/include" \
            PYTHON_LIBS="-L$WINE_PYTHON_PATH/libs -lpython27" \
            PYTHON_LIB_LOC="$WINE_PYTHON_PATH/Lib" \
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$PREFIX/include/glib-2.0 -I$PREFIX/lib/glib-2.0/include/" \
            CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I$PREFIX/include/glib-2.0 -I$PREFIX/lib/glib-2.0/include/"
```

### Configure Linux Python Run

```
./configure --build="$BUILD" --host="$HOST" --prefix="$PREFIX" \
            PKG_CONFIG="$PREFIX/bin/pkg-config.exe" \
            PYTHON="/usr/bin/python2.7" \
            PYTHON_INCLUDES="-I/usr/include/python2.7/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/" \
            PYTHON_LIBS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpython2.7" \
            PYTHON_LIB_LOC="/usr/lib/python2.7/" \
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$PREFIX/include/glib-2.0 -I$PREFIX/lib/glib-2.0/include/" \
            CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I$PREFIX/include/glib-2.0 -I$PREFIX/lib/glib-2.0/include/"
```

Comment: Typically, you just install appropriate cross-compiling tools, then pass `--host=<arch>` to `configure`. It then sets appropriate paths to tools and lookup directories

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, I agree. Typically that is what is usually done. However, in this case things don't seem to be working as one might typically expect. I have added the environment setup script and the configuration lines that I have tried. Is there something that I missed or can you think of something I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this into your Makefile:

```
CFLAGS+=        \
                -DHAVE_SSIZE_T \
                -DPY_FORMAT_SIZE_T="l" \
                -DPY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG="ll" \
```

Comment: I apologize. We spent several days trying to get this done in September of 2014. After being unable to figure it out we had moved on to using something else. As such I was/am unable to test your answer. If someone else can verify that this works I will then click accept.